# Inconsistent results from python 3.3 in interactive and program modes

Tags: function, python-3.3

```
# File function2.py

def f():
  print("I am f")
  return("return f")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print("print(f) gives", end=": "); print(f)
  print("f        gives", end=": "); f
  print("f()      gives", end=": "); f()
```

If you run the code `python function2.py`, you will have

```
print(f) gives: <function f at 0x026CD6F0>
f        gives: f()      gives: I am f
```

However, if you interactively type and execute the code, you will have:

```
>>> def f():
...   print("I am f")
...   return("return f")
...
>>> if __name__ == "__main__":
...   print("print(f) gives", end=": "); print(f)
...   print("f        gives", end=": "); f
...   print("f()      gives", end=": "); f()
...
print(f) gives: <function f at 0x025BD6F0>
f        gives: <function f at 0x025BD6F0>
f()      gives: I am f
'Return f'
>>>
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: I'm not sure what the inconsistency is.  If you type `3` at the console, you see `3` printed out.  But if you simply have a line in a program `3`, you don't see anything printed.  Here you've just substituted `f` for `3`.  Is it how the Python REPL itself works which is puzzling you?

Answer (score 1):

@DSM is right. The thing behind the `;` is a new statement.

What you write is

```
print("print(f) gives", end=": ")
print(f)
print("f        gives", end=": ")
f # this causes the program to just go over it and do nothing but in the REPL this is printing f
print("f()      gives", end=": ")
f()
```

REPL = Read Evaluate Print Loop = interactive interpreter = `>>>`

So you do

```
>>> f # print(f) in REPL
<function f at 0x025BD6F0>
>>> f() # print(f()) in REPL # = print("I am f"); print("return f")
I am f
'return f'
```

So REPL is putting a `print()` around every line of the typed in program.

This is why there is an output. If you want to have it consistent then use `print`.

Comment: However, in the first instance, f() did not return the string but the second instance did. Is there any difference between f() in interactive versus program modes?